# Fibers of double suspension and fundamental class maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

We can take a fundamental class $S^3 \rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}, 3)$ and consider homotopy theoretic fiber of this map $\bar{S}^3$. Then we obtain the following homotopy fiber sequence $\Omega^2\bar{S}^3\rightarrow \Omega^2S^3 \rightarrow \Omega^2K(\mathbb{Z},3)$. Of course, $\Omega^2K(\mathbb{Z},3) = K(\mathbb{Z},1) = S^1$, therefore we obtain fibration $\phi:\Omega^2S^3 \rightarrow S^1$ with fiber $\Omega^2\bar{S}^3$.

Now, consider the double suspension map $E^2: S^1 \rightarrow \Omega^2S^3$ and its homotopy fiber called $W(1)$. What are the compositions $\phi\circ E^2: S^1\rightarrow S^1$ and $E^2\circ\phi: \Omega^2S^3\rightarrow\Omega^2S^3$? Is it true that $W(1)$ is homotopy equivalent to $\Omega^2\bar{S}^3$?

Comment: Since $E^2$ and $\phi$ are both isomorphisms on $\pi_1$, the composite $\phi E^2: S^1\to S^1$ is a homotopy equivalence. It follows that the space $Ω^2S^3$ is homotopy equivalent to a product $S^1\times \Omega^2\bar S^3$. The composide $E^2\phi$ is the projection onto $S^1$, followed by inclusion. Finally, it is not hard to show that if $q\colon X\to Y$ is a map with a section $s$, then the homotopy fiber of $s$ is the loop space of the homotopy fiber of $q$. Thus $W(1)$ is equivalent to $\Omega^3\bar S^3$.

Comment: Therefore $W(1)$ is homotopy equivalent to connected component of $\Omega^3S^3$. Thanks.